# Is it possible to make a method operate sequentially?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, methods, uilabel

I have only included the code relevant to this label within the program.

In my viewDidLoad method I have

```
[startLabel setHidden:NO];
startLabel.text = @"Touch to Begin";
```

In the touchesBegan method I then have

```
startLabel.text = @"Loading . .";
[self fillArrays];
```

Then in the fill Arrays method I fill the arrays and then hide the label -

```
 self.myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"Frame 1.png"], . .etc etc etc . . . nil]];

 [startLabel setHidden:YES];
```

However, the text is not updated before the Array is loaded. Resulting in the "Loading . . " text never appearing. As it seems to be implemented after the Array is filled.

At the same time the setHidden bool is set to YES, thus one never sees the label.

I wish for the startLabel to update before the method begins to fill the Array as this takes some time. i.e. for the method to Operate sequentially.

Is this possible?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the arrays on a different thread to that of your GUI updates.

See this article: http://evilrockhopper.com/2010/01/iphone-development-keeping-the-ui-responsive-and-a-background-thread-pattern/

The function you want is **performSelectorInBackground**

That way your UI updates and your Background work can be done at the same time.

You can run another function which updates the label on the main thread as well in a similar way:

`performSelectorOnMainThread`

That way you load arrays in the background, and you update your UI on the main thread (which is good because I Think the UIKit is not thread safe.

Comment: I think is the right way to go, however that's not going to solve the issue of the label text not changing at the correct time.

Comment: Try using [startLabel setText:@"BLAH"];

Comment: He's already using that (but with Objective-C 2.0 syntax).  Your answer is too general and I think you need to explain how he's going to sync the background thread state with the UI thread label update.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need multithreading, that's overcomplicating things.  The problem is that until your code returns, UIKit isn't going to update the user interface, so you're scheduling the user interface update, loading the arrays, then returning control to UIKit, which then performs the user interface update.  What you need to do is schedule the user interface update, return control to UIKit and then load the arrays in the next iteration of the run loop.  To do that, you can use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` with a zero delay, which executes the method call in the next run loop iteration.  This should do the trick:

```
startLabel.text = @"Loading . .";
[self performSelector:@selector(fillArrays) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

Comment: Thanks @Jim, I got the above method working before I saw this. Would this way be more efficient?